# Android: Add drawable to EditText’s top right corner

Tags: android

I know that in Android we can use function setCompoundDrawables(..) to add drawable.

My problem is that my EditText is multy-lines and i want to put drawable in EditText’s top right corner. Text must wrap and not under the drawable. But using at setCompoundDrawables() function, only give choice to put drawable in specific side.

**EDIT:**

My layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/newpost_textbox_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:maxLines="10"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/newpost_image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/newpost_textbox_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/newpost_textbox_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is the text will be hidden under the Image and can't be seen by users.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using an EditText and an ImageView together?

Comment: use a linear layout with an `EditText` and `ImageView`. Does that work for you?

Comment: @SimonSays because the text will be under the ImageView and become invisible for user.

Comment: @Công Võ Well that really depends on your layout. Show us the layout you are using right now, and we can tell you how to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

[image]

It's simple with LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Line 1 of green Edit Text
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
..."/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**
In case the image should be inside the EditText

[image]

with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Line 1 of green Edit Text
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
..."/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/editText"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/editText"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for this
    [image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

    >
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="#d3d3d3"
        android:id="@+id/et_hint2">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_details"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"

            android:gravity="start"
            android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"
            android:text="wekrbiweubruiweobrfuiwegfiewrbgiuer gurwe bgiewbgu9w engi weig weoihg iwhe gihwebgihwe ghewg hegb iher giewrg iew giwe giwgiwbgiwbgiwbiwbgwijbgiuwbgiwg"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#000000"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:lines="8"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp"
            android:imeOptions="flagNavigateNext"
            android:singleLine="false"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img_camera"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/camera" />
</RelativeLayout>
```